# Is there a standard for including a transcript in an audio podcast RSS feed?

Tags: rss, podcast

I am programmatically generating an RSS feed for an audio podcast. I have transcripts in the form of subtitle (SRT) files for each audio file.

Is there a standard or norm, de-facto or de-jure, for adding transcript or lyrics files to the feed?

```
rss
 +- channel
 |   +- item
 |   |   +- enclosure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Standard" is a relative term, but there is some consolidation around the "RSS Namespace Extension for Podcasting" extension to RSS (https://podcastindex.org/namespace/1.0).

As long as you have `xmlns:podcast="https://podcastindex.org/namespace/1.0"` in your root `rss` tag, you can use the `podcast:transcript` element under `item`.

```
rss
 +- channel
 |   +- item
 |   |   +- podcast:transcript
```

It has a `url` attribute which should be the *fully qualified* URL to the transcript file, and can specify a `type`  attribute to indicate whether it is text, HTML, JSON or SubRip format.

See https://podcastindex.org/namespace/1.0#transcript for more information.